# SQL sum rows and select one unique id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am seeking a method of summing multiple rows and selecting the Unique id of one of the rows to be the Unique id for the sum row.. if that makes sence?

For example if I have a table like this

```
ID       | Value1      Value2     Text1        Text2
---------|-------------------------------------------
1        |   100         150      Bananas      Hawaii
2        |   200         100      Bananas      Hawaii
3        |   300         200      Bananas      Hawaii
---------|--------------------------------------------
1,2 or 3 |   600         450      Bananas      Hawaii
```

To get the result row I would do something like this

```
SELECT 
  sum(Value1) as Value1
  sum(Value2) as Value2
FROM
  db..table
GROUP BY
  Text1
  ,Text2
```

However I need to retrieve just one of the ID's to put on my results row, I don't care wether it would be 1, 2 or 3.

The reason for this is, I have a massive database and a big program to retrieve data, but due to some new programming I can suddenly now have more of the same row, but with different Unique ids, hence I am interrested in summing the rows and just keeping one of the Unique ids.

Assigning a new Unique ID to the result row will not help me because of the way everything is designed right now.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Just add `MIN(ID)` or `MAX(ID)` to your `SELECT` list.

Comment: Min/Max worked perfectly - didn't even think of that, thanks ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use another aggregate like `MIN` or `MAX`

```
SELECT min(ID) as ID
  ,sum(Value1) as Value1
  ,sum(Value2) as Value2
FROM
  db..table
GROUP BY
  Text1
  ,Text2
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
SELECT 
  min(ID) as ID,
  sum(Value1) as Value1,
  sum(Value2) as Value2
FROM
  db..table
GROUP BY
  Text1
  ,Text2
```